# de facto standard for uml

Tags: uml

I am facing problem with uml where there is different interpretation from different people. anyone have de facto standard for uml?

Comment: UML diagramming is noting like "draw a line with a ruler". It's more like paint a picture of ... in ... style. You will not find an answer to your question here.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one standard for UML and that is defined by OMG.

It is available at the website of [OMG](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/)